# Laravel - plugin para ver pastas e ficheiros existentes em Storage->app->public

Tags: laravel, arquivo, treeview

preciso de uma ajuda, alguém conhece algum plugin para mostrar em tempo real as pastas e ficheiros existentes no Storage>>app>>public em Laravel?

Encontrei esse plugin que faz o que eu quero:
Demo:
https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/

Mas não sei converter o ficheiro **scan.php** para um código compreensivel pelo Laravel 5.4

O código PHP do ficheiro Scan:

```html
<?php

$dir = "files";

// Run the recursive function 

$response = scan($dir);


// This function scans the files folder recursively, and builds a large array

function scan($dir){

 $files = array();

 // Is there actually such a folder/file?

 if(file_exists($dir)){
 
  foreach(scandir($dir) as $f) {
  
   if(!$f || $f[0] == '.') {
    continue; // Ignore hidden files
   }

   if(is_dir($dir . '/' . $f)) {

    // The path is a folder

    $files[] = array(
     "name" => $f,
     "type" => "folder",
     "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
     "items" => scan($dir . '/' . $f) // Recursively get the contents of the folder
    );
   }
   
   else {

    // It is a file

    $files[] = array(
     "name" => $f,
     "type" => "file",
     "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
     "size" => filesize($dir . '/' . $f) // Gets the size of this file
    );
   }
  }
 
 }

 return $files;
}



// Output the directory listing as JSON

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
 "name" => "files",
 "type" => "folder",
 "path" => $dir,
 "items" => $response
));
```

Comment: Onde está o seu arquivo scan.php?

Comment: Ademilson podes fazer o download do pacote neste link https://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php

Comment: Por que diz que o código não é compreensível pelo Laravel 5.4? É uma função apenas, creio que possa colocar isso dentro de uma classe (que você deverá criar) e chamar ela no ponto do código que quiser, não seria isso?

Comment: Já tentei utilizar mais não mostrou o directório seleccionado

Comment: Mas o código é simples, basta ver se você estava olhando para o diretório correto.
Tentou exibir um print no diretório em que estava tentando listar? Ou ainda já viu se tem essa permissão na pasta p/ fazer isso?
Precisa ir debugando ponto a ponto, todavia o código eu garanto que é válido para o Laravel 5.4 (do contrário você teria erros na tela)...

Comment: O meu problema é implementar a função no respectivo controller em Laravel, especialmente o header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Já deu uma lida na parte que falta sobre HTTP Responses na doc do Laravel 5.4? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses
Lá explica como retornar com esse tipo de header...